# Type 'PostView.Type' cannot conform to 'View'

Tags: swiftui

SwiftUIで

```swift
ToolbarItem(placement: .bottomBar) {
  Button(action: { NavigationLink {NextView} }) { }
```

とすると

Type 'PostView.Type' cannot conform to 'View'

というアラートが出ます。

actionではNavigationLinkは使えないのでしょうか。

Answer (score 0):

Buttonのactionは関数などは使用できますが、Viewそのものは渡せません。
コードが一部なので、合っているかはわかりませんが、以下のようには可能です。

```swift
struct ContentView: View {  
  var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
      Text("Hello")
        .toolbar {
          ToolbarItem(placement: .bottomBar) {
            NavigationLink("NextView") {
              NextView()
            }
          }
        }
    }
  }
}
```